# aptana 3 windows - terminal access denied

Tags: windows, eclipse, permissions, aptana

Wen I open the Antapa studio 3 terminal from specific project it notice me an error:

> Permission denied to access C:\www\drupal\sites\all. Using default working
>   directory instead.

Also, I can get to the dir by `cd C:\www\drupal\sites\all` so it pretty wired.. 
Is somone handle with this issue, or is smone have any idea?

~ Almog Baku

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how exactly that solved.. but it seems that it works after computer format and installing aptana again.

if this bug is happening for you try to reinstall aptana.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.  You have described it exactly.  I found no solution but here's my workaround.  First, I want an EXTERNAL terminal window because the Aptana terminal window is too inconvenient for running git and rspec from the command line, so my solution always opens to the current project directory.  Also note that I'm on a Mac and my solution is Mac specific.

From the Command menu, I selected Shell Script, and used the "Edit this Bundle" option.  After some head scratching, I found that the bundle had been opened as a new project.  Then I edited the open_directory_in_terminal.rb file to this:

```
require 'ruble'

command t(:open_terminal) do |cmd|
  cmd.key_binding = 'M2+M4+O'
  cmd.output = :output_to_console
  cmd.working_directory = :current_project
  cmd.invoke do |context|
    `open -a Terminal.app "#{ENV['TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY']}"`
  end
end
```

Basically, all this does is use the Mac OS "open" command to open the Mac terminal app on the current directory.  I am sure there are more elegant (and platform independent) ways to do this, but this is what I am using.  Hope it gives you some ideas.

FYI, docs on editing the bundle items are here:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Rubles

Comment: I am fairly sure the
  cmd.output = :output_to_console
  cmd.working_directory = :current_project
lines don't really do anything useful here, but it works so I am done messing with this.